# Change theme dynamically then change background of a LinearLayout fails

Tags: android, android-layout

I can change the Theme based on a dialog of different choices but I also want to change the background color of a few LinearLayouts to something else but it doesn't take effect. Any changes to the Layouts don't change and still have the background color of the theme.

Portion of onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    colorBackgroundBlock = prefs.getInt("colorBackgroundBlock",R.color.block_main);
    colorTheme = prefs.getInt("colorTheme", R.style.defaultTheme);
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this, colorTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout freeLinearLayoutBlock = (LinearLayout)
    findViewById(R.id.freeLinearLayoutBlock);
    // **** this is what doesn't change now  *****
    freeLinearLayoutBlock.setBackgroundResource(colorBackgroundBlock);
}
```

My Utils class:

```
public class Utils{
public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity)
{
    activity.finish();
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
}

public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
{
    activity.setTheme(theme);
}
}
```

Sample of my theme style

```
<style name="defaultTheme" >
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_main</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_main</item>
</style>
```

Here's how I call the theme change:

```
Utils.changeToTheme(MainActivity.this);
```

I save the theme reference in preferences so the user gets their last selected theme when they restart the app. Also, I have an imageView (set with a .png image) within the LinearLayout to change and the imageView background will change to the color I want, just not the rest of the layout. This all worked for me without the overall theme part, I thought adding a dynamic theme instead of changing every layout and view individually might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

This won't fully answer your question, but help you to understand how to alternativly set themes: [Android Set Theme Dynamically](http://javarticles.com/2015/04/android-set-theme-dynamically.html)

To set the LinearLayout background depending on which theme is active you can use attributes. For this take a look at this [Android Themes, Styles and Attributes](http://codetheory.in/android-themes-styles-and-attributes/)

**Simplified:**

```
<!-- values/attr.xml -->
<resources>
    <attr name="testcolor" format="color" />
    ..
</resources>

<!-- values/styles.xml -->
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="backgroundLinearLayout">@color/backgroundLinearLayout</item>
        ..
    </style>
    ..
</resources>

<!-- layout/layout_1.xml -->
<LinearLayout
   ..
   android:background="?attr/backgroundLinearLayout">
</LinearLayout>
```